# what is the simplest way to have text show if a tableview section is empty?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

Preferably without looking like a cell. I would like to display "tap edit in the upper right to add syllables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to implement the `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` method in the class that implements `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: Simple indeed. I knew i was over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a sub view to your tableView with the same bounds should do it.